# How safe and secure is RSA?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I am using RSA for encryption and decryption. I've heard that it's vulnerable to attacks. Is it? How safe is it to use?

Comment: Safer than the software on either end.

Comment: You might get better answers to this question on [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: google `rsa timing attack` and `rsa chosen ciphertext attack`

Comment: @SLaks: Its a reasonable question for a person who wants to learn. There is no need to be condescending.

Comment: RSA is a factoring-based algorithm, and computing power grows constantly, and people all over are working on breaking RSA factorization. RSA-1024 is probably the most widely used bit strength/number, as it's used in SSL, so it's considered safe enough to protect much of the sensitive data flowing through the internet. Though there will come a time (probably soon) when RSA-2048 will be the default used because breaking RSA-1024 is becoming more real every day.

Comment: @noMAD, SLaks' questions are reasonable, and would help focus the question. It's important to understand who you're defending against, as Angelo notes in his answer.

Comment: @birryree currently, according to both NIST and ECRYPTII 1024 is a bit on the short side for most systems, I would go for a larger key if possible (see [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/) which handily aggregates the key length recommendations for multiple situations).

Comment: @owlstead - Yeah the big worry is that RSA-1024 will be broken in a near time frame (several years), so RSA-2048 should become the recommended bit length.

Comment: Hello 2020, quantum computers, Shor's algorithm, RSA gets cracked.

Answer (score 37):

The usual attack on RSA involves factoring a large number which is the product of two very large prime numbers. The general idea behind this is that finding prime numbers is fairly easy, and multiplying them together to get a single large number is also quite easy, but if you only start with that large number, finding the factors is *quite* hard.

Back when they were an independent company, RSA Data Security Inc., ran a factoring challenge. IIRC, the last few prizes were won by teams from RSA DSI themselves. These were done using the General Number Field Sieve (GNFS). The typical implementation uses a large number of workstations for a few months or so to build a "factor base". Then (the hard part) you feed that to a single machine with *gargantuan* amounts of RAM (think terabytes as a starting point) and have it crunch for a few weeks to get the factors.

The point of that is to point out that the most common attack on RSA has a *very* high initial cost (i.e., getting something like a Cray supercomputer) to even get started. In all honesty, however, I don't believe any machine currently exists that can hold enough RAM to even begin an attack on something like a 1024-bit RSA key (not to mention the 2048 or even 4096-bit keys some of the paranoid types insist on using).

There are, of course, other factoring methods that don't require that huge machine, but they're enough less efficient that even at best, you'd be looking at years of work to break even a fairly small key by RSA standards -- 512 bits, for example.

Realistically, the security of RSA itself is generally the least of your concerns in designing a system that uses it. In fact, that's true of nearly all reasonably modern encryption algorithms. When something gets broken into, it's essentially never by actually breaking the fundamental algorithm involved -- it's by finding weaknesses in how keys are distributed, "social engineering" attacks, etc.

While (as I said) this tends to be true of encryption in general, it's even more consistently true with RSA than most other encryption. This is simply because the normal use-case for RSA is comparatively complex. In particular, you do *not* normally want to use RSA to encrypt large streams of raw data. RSA is slow enough that you generally do not want to use it to encrypt a lot of data. Instead, you typically use RSA in conjunction with some symmetric-key (aka private key) encryption algorithm such as AES.

When using the two together, you start by getting the public key of the person to whom you want to send some data. You then generate a random number of the correct size to be used as the key with the symmetric algorithm you've chosen. You encrypt your random number with RSA and send it to the target. You then use that number as the key with the symmetric algorithm, and use that symmetric algorithm to encrypt the actual data.

This means that in real use, RSA has some weaknesses that don't necessarily apply to most symmetric encryption algorithms. Just for an obvious example, if the method use to choose the "random" key for the symmetric algorithm isn't really entirely random, an attacker may be able find the key and decrypt the data, without attacking the RSA encryption itself at all (and yes, this has been the source of a real vulnerability in real, publicly released software).

Also note that what I've described above is pretty much the simplest way that RSA is normally put to use. Real systems often get considerably more complex still to provide such things as "perfect forward secrecy"<sup>1</sup>. The RSA in such a system is still perfectly normal RSA, but the rest of the system that uses it is considerably more complex still.

Summary: if you're going to use RSA encryption, the security of RSA itself is probably the least of your concerns. The route from "RSA" to "secure communication system" is a bit like something out of a twisted combination of Greek mythology and the Christian Bible: a maze with a thousand wrong turns, each of which leads to a place that looks exactly like where you wanted to go--but taking any wrong turn will damn you to an eternity of torture and torment.

---

<sup>1. No, I'm not going to try to describe this right now, but I'm sure searching for it on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions) will turn up some relevant results. I should probably add, however, that although RSA can be used in a system that provides PFS, it's fairly unusual in practice.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Assume RSA is safe for all your realistic needs.

But of course it depends on what you are doing, how you do it and whom you want to defend against.

If you want to secure your connection and you stick to the usual recommended stuff RSA is safe enough.

If you want to run a covert operation under the NSA nose, then you have lost already because you have to ask such a question.

PS: You may want to have a look at the [IT-Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) Site here on StackExchange for stuff like this..

Comment: You have still not answered the asker's question. Instead of talking about NSA, covert operations and all you could have given the answer.

Comment: @Ashwin The question was too vague to be answered shortly. With my answer I wanted to point out that the span of this question is too large to be answerable in a short sentence. If the OP clarifies what he wants to do, I'll sure edit the answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @Ashwin but I've edited the answer to have the relevant part up front.

Comment: @Angelo Neuschitzer I am running an web app. I have used html and jsp pages for client side and Java Servlets at server end. I have used https connection between them So on security aspect, What should i do if I want this https connection to be safe?

Comment: @suraj Nothing more. Https will most likely fit your needs. (Even banks use it, and they are paranoid). You have to be sure that you guard your server-side certificate / keys very well (this is often the weakest point). You may want to ask a best-practice question on the IT-Security site I've linked.

Comment: "If you want to run a covert operation under the NSA nose, then you have lost already because you have to ask such a question." Didn't the NSA insert a backdoor in Dual-EC-DRGB, which was used in RSA?

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 Not that I know of, but if you are so novice that this question here is something you want to ask, then you are not advanced enough to take them on.

Answer (score 6):

Implemented correctly (i.e., if you use an existing library that does this for you), your data channel is secure. However, remember that the point of encryption is simply to make the data channel *not* the weakest point in your entire system. RSA will do this, but you still need to worry about the other parts of your system and how secure they are.